# How do make a UserControl in Silverlight reload each xx time?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I have a UserControl in silverlight (GraphToolKit) that needs to be refreshed each xx seconds.
How do i make that happen? i am still new with threads and timers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent328.aspx) is an article that explains how to use a Dispatcher to refresh the data withing xx secounds using Silverlight charts.

Hope this helps.